# Why does a button return to its original position when I change its background image?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a button which has been placed in the Storyboard on a `UIViewController` and has a bottom space constraint of `-500` attached to it which means it isn't visible in the superView. A function brings it up so that it is visible when it's needed.

The same button has a background image which gets changed by tapping it:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

        let image1a = UIImage(named: "NewImage")
        button.setImage(image1a, forState: .Selected)
}
```

However, when the button changes its background it returns to its original position. This means it is no longer visible in the superView. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My psychic powers tell me you're "bringing it up" by changing the view's frame.  You need to modify the constraint constant, or anytime something causes the view to invalidate its layout (such as changing the image, most likely) the layout engine will re-apply the constraints.